# pgfgantt hide overlapping date

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I am trying to hide any Date in the second row (in this case the Nov 14th) that will overlap at the border of the chart. Does anybody know how to do that, thanks in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1cm,top=1cm,%
bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}


\ganttset{%
calendar week text={%
\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\startmonth}~\startday, \startyear%
}%
}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{plain}\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
            hgrid=true,
            vgrid=true,
            y unit title=0.9cm,
            y unit chart=0.6cm,
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
            progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
            ]{1}{35}
\gantttitle{Projektplan}{35} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[time slot format=little-endian]{10.10.2022}{14.11.2022}{week, day} \\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{35} \\

\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know much about pgfgantt but doesn't just using `13.11.2022` in `\gantttitlecalendar` help?

Comment: I wish I could do that, but I really need the 14th to be in the same chart still. Appreciate your response though!

Comment: But then you have 36 days and not 35 (which would at least help with the rest of the diagram to cover the 14th). Then you can use `\ifdate{2022-11-14}{}{\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\startmonth}~\startday, \startyear}` in `calendar week text` to supress the last week, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you're displaying 36 days thus I changed every ocurrence of `35` into `36`.

For the last day, I've changed the `calendar week text` so that it checks for the last day in the calendar and doesn't actually print anything than (there might be a way to add a similar test to the option of those nodes and turn that node into an `coordinate` or emptying out `calendar week text` but this simple enough.

I'm using `\pgfcalendarendiso` which is the last day of the calendar in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you could of course just explicitly write `2022-11-14` there.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\ganttset{%
  calendar week text={%
    \ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarendiso}{}{%
      \pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\startmonth}~\startday, \startyear
    }%
  }
}
%\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{plain}\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
            hgrid=true,
            vgrid=true,
            y unit title=0.9cm,
            y unit chart=0.6cm,
            bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
            progress label text={\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
            ]{1}{36}
\gantttitle{Projektplan}{36} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[time slot format=little-endian]{10.10.2022}{14.11.2022}{week, day} \\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\

\end{ganttchart}
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for what I wanted to do. Thanks a ton!